# Python - Cannot import name Eve

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, eve

I'm trying to set setup Python-Eve.

[Python-Eve Installation Guide](http://python-eve.org/install.html)

I've finished these steps:

```
C:\Users\Ari\Desktop\rizzla>python -m pip install eve
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): eve in c:\python34\lib
\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cerberus<0.9,>=0.8 in
c:\python34\lib\site-packages (from eve)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): events<0.3,>=0.2.1   in
c:\python34\lib\site-packages (from eve)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):   simplejson<4.0,>=3.3.0
 in c:\python34\lib\site-packages (from eve)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):   werkzeug<0.10,>=0.9.4
in c:\python34\lib\site-packages (from eve)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):     markupsafe<1.0,>=0.23
in c:\python34\lib\site-packages (from eve)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): jinja2<3.0,>=2.7.2  in
c:\python34\lib\site-packages (from eve)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):     itsdangerous<1.0,>=0.2
2 in c:\python34\lib\site-packages (from eve)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):   flask<0.11,>=0.10.1 in
 c:\python34\lib\site-packages (from eve)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):  pymongo<3.0,>=2.7.1 in
 c:\python34\lib\site-packages (from eve)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): flask- pymongo<0.4,>=0.
3.0 in c:\python34\lib\site-packages (from eve)
```

But when trying to run the code on [Quick Start Guide](http://python-eve.org/quickstart.html) I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
 from eve import Eve
File "C:\Users\Ari\Desktop\rizzla\eve.py", line 1, in <module>
   from eve import Eve
 ImportError: cannot import name 'Eve'
```

My code is here:

```
from eve import Eve

app = Eve()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script name is `eve`; same as the module you want to import. Rename your script name to other name to prevent the conflict.

Remove `eve.pyc` in the directory if there is.

Comment: It's allways something simple isnt it. Thanks for the help, that fixed it!